# Response/request object for .save() in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, promise, jquery-deferred

In the below function as you can see in the .save() part there is no response object, I would like to know how do i declare a response object to get a return value.

```
        $.when(
            _this.formWebsitePart.save({
                success: function () {
                    console.log("website saved")
                    _this.formWebsitePart.isSaved = true;
                }
            }),
            _this.formAddressPart.save({
                success: function () {
                    console.log("address saved")
                }
            })
        ).then(function () {
                _this.signupSuccess();
            }
        )
```

Comment: @Bergi Its just that i need to get a response from the .save function.

Comment: The docs say that `.save()` returns a jqXHR object. Isn't that (being a promise instance) enough?

Comment: exactly, but in the above code doesn't seem to work, i think thats because .save() is not returning anything right?

Comment: What does not work? What happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: can you please tell me how to use that return in the .when promise object?

Comment: the  signupsuccess () gets executed , irrespective of what happens in the $.when()

Comment: Are you sure that `.save()` did return promises? It seems that when failing validation it might return `false`, which `$.when` won't like.

Comment: can you tell me how actually you initiate a  promise inside .save()

Comment: No idea, the docs say it returns a jqXHR object which is an initiated promise.

Comment: ya the problem i am facing is handling that jqXHR object.

Answer (score 0):

If your `.save()` genuinely returns a jqXHR object, then you probably want something like this :

```
_this.saveFormParts = function() {
    if(!_this.formWebsitePart.jqXHR) {
        _this.formWebsitePart.jqXHR = _this.formWebsitePart.save().then(function(response) {
            console.log("website saved");
            return response || null;
        });
    }
    if(!_this.formAddressPart.jqXHR) {
        _this.formAddressPart.jqXHR = _this.formAddressPart.save().then(function(response) {
            console.log("address saved");
            return response || null;
        });
    }
    return $.when(
        _this.formWebsitePart.jqXHR,
        _this.formAddressPart.jqXHR
    );
}
```

And, wherever appropriate :

```
_this.saveFormParts().then(_this.signupSuccess); // or similar
```

If your `.save()` doesn't return a jqXHR object, then you will need to do one of the following :

- write a promisified version of `.save()` (preferred)
- write a promisified version of `.saveFormParts()`

For promisification of a conventional callback interface - [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)